# MY android application is crashing when I click on the register btn

Tags: java, android

While running my application I go to click on the register button and the application is crashing. Please find Log-cat below (if anyone could explain the best way to use log-cat that would be great) I have also included the register Java. If there is any more information you need comment and I will update this message.

```
04-23 21:52:07.835: D/libEGL(28588): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so 
04-23 21:52:07.875: D/libEGL(28588): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so 
04-23 21:52:07.885: D/libEGL(28588): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so 
04-23 21:52:07.895: E/(28588): Device driver API match 
04-23 21:52:07.895: E/(28588): Device driver API version: 23 
04-23 21:52:07.895: E/(28588): User space API version: 23 
04-23 21:52:07.895: E/(28588):  mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
04-23 21:52:08.000: D/OpenGLRenderer(28588): Enabling debug mode 0 
04-23 21:52:24.925: D/AndroidRuntime(28588): Shutting down VM 
04-23 21:52:24.925: W/dalvikvm(28588): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ba8700) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loggedin/com.loggedin.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at com.loggedin.Register.onCreate(Register.java:83) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-23 21:52:24.930: E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

the following code is the Register page

package com.loggedin;

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.loggedin.internal.DatabaseHandler;
 import com.loggedin.internal.UserFunctions;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;

public class Register extends Activity {
/**
 *  JSON Response node names.
 **/
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "id";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "LastName";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_DOB = "DOB";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
/**
 * Defining layout items.
 **/
EditText inputFirstName;
EditText inputLastName;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputDOB;
EditText inputPassword;
Button btnRegister;
TextView registerErrorMsg;
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
/**
 * Defining all layout items
 **/
    inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
    inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LastName);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DOB);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn1);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);
   /**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologinbtn);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });
    /**
     * Register Button click event.
     * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
     * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
     **/
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
       if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && (      !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals(""))  && ( !inputDOB.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                InternetAsync(view);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
   }
 /**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
 **/
  private class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean>   {
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){
/**
* Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
**/
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)   getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessRegister().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}
  private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask <String, String, JSONObject>{
  /**
 * Defining Process dialog
 **/
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String email,Password,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Username;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
           FirstName = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
           LastName = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            DOB = inputDOB.getText().toString();
            Username= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            Password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(FirstName, LastName, DOB, email, Username, Password);
        return json;
    }
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
   /**
    * Checks for success message.
    **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/
             Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Registered.class);
                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                        **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);
                          finish();
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }
                }
                    else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
     public void InternetAsync(View view){
         new InternetCheck().execute();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike already said, debugger can really help you find the issue.
In this case, the line is:

```
 btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

The problem is when you use findViewById:

```
public View findViewById (int id)
Added in API level 1
Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

Returns
The view if found or null otherwise.
```

This means that findViewById returns a null pointer :) so, check your id in the XML layout.

Comment: OK, I was going to say that too but when I finished typing you already posted this. :) 
But Mike is right: You should learn how to use the Logcat debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Some advice when using logcat...

E/AndroidRuntime(28588): **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
E/AndroidRuntime(28588): at
com.loggedin.Register.onCreate(**Register.java:83**)

You can always do a quick text search checking out the caused By: you can find out where you went wrong.Logcat also shows where the error was thrown too in your case line #83.

I'd recommend looking into how to use the debugger properly too, it is pretty important:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious and ppl correctly said regarding using debugger and logcat..

Anyways following are my views :-
1. plz cross check your xml file activity_register.xml dat it has the id which you are using here.

1. since the error is happening in onclick of the button and then try to capture everything inside onlick in exception using try - catch also surrond the whole button click inside try-catch . add two Toast with different msgs as to identify where the exception is raised.
2. also u can simply add Log msg like this Log.e("IS_REGISTER_BUTTON_NULL","Value : " +btnRegister) in on create after getting the id if its not null it will write some character other then null. also remove everything inside the onlick and see for each string values u r taking like

String uName=inputUsername.getText().toString(); 
String pWd=inputPassword.getText().toString();
.
.
.

Log.e("CHECKING_IF_STRING_ARE_NULL",uName+" "+pWd+" "+eMail+.....);

thx